# Whats the bare minimum modules required by Apache to run Drupal

Tags: apache-2.2, drupal7

As part of improving performance of my website I am reducing the memory footprint of Apache. Currently I have the following modules enabled

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Aug 31  2012 alias.conf -> ../mods-available/alias.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Aug 31  2012 alias.load -> ../mods-available/alias.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Aug 31  2012 auth_basic.load -> ../mods-available/auth_basic.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Aug 31  2012 authn_file.load -> ../mods-available/authn_file.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   36 Aug 31  2012 authz_default.load -> ../mods-available/authz_default.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   38 Aug 31  2012 authz_groupfile.load -> ../mods-available/authz_groupfile.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Aug 31  2012 authz_host.load -> ../mods-available/authz_host.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Aug 31  2012 authz_user.load -> ../mods-available/authz_user.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Aug 31  2012 autoindex.conf -> ../mods-available/autoindex.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Aug 31  2012 autoindex.load -> ../mods-available/autoindex.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Aug 31  2012 cgi.load -> ../mods-available/cgi.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Aug 31  2012 deflate.conf -> ../mods-available/deflate.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Aug 31  2012 deflate.load -> ../mods-available/deflate.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Aug 31  2012 dir.conf -> ../mods-available/dir.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Aug 31  2012 dir.load -> ../mods-available/dir.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   26 Aug 31  2012 env.load -> ../mods-available/env.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Aug 31  2012 headers.load -> ../mods-available/headers.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Aug 31  2012 mime.conf -> ../mods-available/mime.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Aug 31  2012 mime.load -> ../mods-available/mime.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Aug 31  2012 negotiation.conf -> ../mods-available/negotiation.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Aug 31  2012 negotiation.load -> ../mods-available/negotiation.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Aug 31  2012 php5.conf -> ../mods-available/php5.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Aug 31  2012 php5.load -> ../mods-available/php5.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Aug 31  2012 reqtimeout.conf -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   33 Aug 31  2012 reqtimeout.load -> ../mods-available/reqtimeout.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Aug 31  2012 rewrite.load -> ../mods-available/rewrite.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Aug 31  2012 setenvif.conf -> ../mods-available/setenvif.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Aug 31  2012 setenvif.load -> ../mods-available/setenvif.load
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Aug 31  2012 status.conf -> ../mods-available/status.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Aug 31  2012 status.load -> ../mods-available/status.load
```

I would like Apache to load only modules required to run Drupal 7. I don't intend to use content negotiation so I can disable it. Are there any other modules that I can disable in the above list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not such important thing to disable these modules.

But if you really want to, you probably can disable all auth* modules as there is "form based" authentication as default in Drupal, which does not need any support from these modules.

Status is not needed if you do not want "server-status" page.

You do not need mod_cgi if your PHP works as Apache module.

I don't think Drupal makes use of directory listings, so you probably do not need mod_autoindex either.

Comment: Thank you. Just disabled the modules. Disabling Directory module throws an error so I guess its required by Drupal.

Comment: Sorry, I meant mod_autoindex, not mod_dir. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok. Let me try disabling it. But will have to wait till my User Acceptance test is complete.